# how to edit file in a separated screen window in vifm version > 0.4

Tags: command-line-tool

I just installed vifm-0.7.4. It included much more functions than version 0.4. However, I am missing one behavior in the old version. That is, if you enable `screen` in `vifm`:

```
:screen
```

once you press <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a text file, the file will be open in `vi` in a new `screen` window. However, in the new version, the file is open in the same window as `vifm` interface. I can open the file in a new `screen` window using the `edit` command:

```
:e
```

But it is less convenient than a single <kbd>l</kbd>. Is it possible to go back to the old behavior in the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a regression, which wasn't noticed until now. I'll fix the bug in the next release (it should be easy), but you could just ask me about such behavior by email or on one of bug trackers.

Here is something you can try to use for now (put it to your `~/.vifm/vifmrc` file):

```
nnoremap l : if filetype('.') == 'reg'
          \|     edit
          \| else
          \|     execute 'normal! l'
          \| endif<cr>

nmap <cr> l
nmap <right> l
```

But this won't run programs, associated with files.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I could have asked you by Email. But I thought maybe other people is interested in this issue as well, or I just simply missed something in the setup file. I am sorry if I annoyed you by asking this here. Looking forward to the new release.

Comment: Note that the trailing spaces (after 'edit' and 'normal! l') in the above snippet seem to be important. Otherwise I get a 'trailing characters' error.